# CSS Transition works on Chrome but not in firefox or Safari?

Tags: css, html, css-transitions

I have been following mozilla developer network's docs and created a transition for my images to change. They seem to work fine in Chrome (19?) but not in Firefox 11 (or any other browser).

I have created a test case here on jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/9nevB/1/
I've tried this in many different ways and still can't get it to work on firefox.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You cannot fade background-images in a transition - only move them. And this does not work in Chrome 17.

Comment: Sorry I meant Chrome 19 it seems to work on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [CSS3 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-image), `background-image` is not animatable. Browsers may provide this implementation, but it is not standardized.

Comment: Thanks. Ive just had a look at this: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/ which seems to have some good workarounds